# Why 'companion' is not applicable inside object?

Tags: java, object, kotlin, companion-object

I'm trying to understand the reason why an object (singleton) can't have an inner companion. For example the following code isn't compiled:

```
object JustAClass
{
    companion object  justACompanion
    {
        fun justAFunc() {
        }
    }
}
```

because of:

> Modifier 'companion' is not applicable inside object

**But** if I'm omitting the *companion* the code is being compiled.

Comment: Why do you need to define a `companion object` inside `object`? Just declare them as top-level `objects` or if you want to have something like namespace, just define it inside `sealed class` or `interface`.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu,Can you please explain why it isn't reasonable to use 
 a **companion** inside an  **object**? there isn't a big difference between writing *object justAnObject* and *companion object JustAnObject*, so why the first syntax is valid and the second one isn't? (sorry that i don't know how to highlight parts of the commet)

Comment: `SomeObject.doSomething()` and `CompanionObject.doSomething()` it serves the same purpose

Comment: @cutiko, that's why i can't understand why companion isn't valid here

Comment: Because it's already an object

Comment: You can take a look at the official guide: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations.
With companion you have a class attached, also you don't need a name, without companion, you don't need a class but you need a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A companion object is just a nested object that can be referenced by its container class's name as a shortcut. This doesn't make sense if the container class is an object, because the outer object's name is how you reference it. There would be no way to distinguish between them, so marking the nested object as a `companion` would provide no functionality besides the implicit name `Companion`. You can still nest an object in another object to organize your code.

Comment: between who it won't be possible to distinguish? What is the problem  in writing: **JustAClass.JustACompanion.justAFunc()**  ?

Comment: No problem with writing that, but then you aren't using any of the functionality of a companion object, just a nested object. The only functionality `companion` gives you is that you can call it by its outer class's name. But if the outer class is an object, then they could both be called by the outer class's name, leading to ambiguity.

Comment: When you are saying **they both** , do you mean to situation when in addition to the companion method, i also have a member function with the same name?

Comment: You're suggesting that you should be able to mark the nested object of another object as a `companion`. The `companion` keyword would allow the nested object to be called by its containing object's name. It would become ambiguous which one you are referring to. That's why it's not allowed. The compiler must always know exactly which class you are referring to.

Comment: the ambiguous may occur if i will add a member function with the same name as i defined inside the companion? In my case , if i will add **.justAFunc()** to outer class?

Comment: It's ambiguous even if there are no function names in common between the objects. If you write`println(MyObject)`, it wouldn't know which object you are passing. But you can just move your function to the outer object. The only reason to nest an object in another object might be to organize your code. I think it would be rarely done in practice.

Answer (score 2):

`companion object` is something common for all instances of class. `object` - is a singleton, hence "all instances of class" == "this only instance". So there is no point in declaration of `companion object` inside `object`, just declare all members supposed to be in companion object directly as members of your `object`:

```kotlin
object JustAClass {
    fun justAFunc() {
    }
}
```

Anyway syntactically they are accesed identically:

```kotlin
JustAClass.justAFunc()
```

Comment: Isn't a companion also acts as a singleton?  I didn't understand the equation: * "all instances of class" == "this only instance"*

Comment: Yes, companion object is a singleton too. This equation means that there is one and only one instance of `JustAClass` class (you can't create more with `JustAClass()`), so there is no point in sharing `companion object` between them, cause there is no _them_.

Comment: And is there a point for creating an object (without the **companion**)? Because this case is valid

Comment: Personally I've never wrote such code, but generally speaking, there could be reasons for this, especially, if this inner `object` has `private` modifier (see [Why Use Nested Classes?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) section, I believe they all applicable for singletons too).